# numpy - tuple is not "(...)" in numpy?

Tags: numpy, tuples, slice

My understanding of tuple is it can be enclosed with parenthesis.

- [class tuple([iterable])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)

> Tuples may be constructed in a number of ways:
>
> Using a pair of parentheses to denote the empty tuple: ()
> Using a trailing comma for a singleton tuple: a, or (a,)
> Separating items with commas: a, b, c or (a, b, c)
> Using the tuple() built-in: tuple() or tuple(iterable)

[Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) says slice indexing is a tuple of slice objects and int.

> Basic slicing occurs when obj is a slice object (constructed by
> start:stop:step notation inside of brackets), an integer, or **a tuple
> of slice objects and integers**.

However, `(...)` cannot be used causing an error. Is the error from numpy or Python?

I suppose without parenthesis, `0:1, 2:3, 1` is still a tuple but why cannot use parenthesis if it is specified as `a tuple of slice objects and integers`?

It is not so important but after struggling with numpy indexing, this makes it further confusing, hence a clarification would help.

```
Z = np.arange(36).reshape(3, 3, 4)
print("Z is \n{}\n".format(Z))

a = Z[
    (0:1, 2:3, 1)
]
---
  File "<ipython-input-53-26b1604433cd>", line 5
    (0:1, 2:3, 1)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This works.

```
Z = np.arange(36).reshape(3, 3, 4)
print("Z is \n{}\n".format(Z))

a = Z[
    0:1, 2:3, 1
]
print(a)
print(a.base is not None)
```

---

As per the comment by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), numpy `s_` internally takes "a list of slices and integers" and returns a tuple of slice objects.

```
from numpy import s_
print(s_[0:1, 2:3, 1])

Z = np.arange(36).reshape(3, 3, 4)
print("Z is \n{}\n".format(Z))

print(Z[s_[0:1, 2:3, 1]])
---
(slice(0, 1, None), slice(2, 3, None), 1)
Z is 
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26 27]
  [28 29 30 31]
  [32 33 34 35]]]

[[9]]
```

Comment: There's a numpy indexing tool that can turn slice and ellipsis syntax into a tuple of objects: `np.s_[1:2, ...]` produces a tuple: `(slice(1, 2, None), Ellipsis)`.  Note that `s_` is used with [], not ().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slice notation like `1:2` is syntax, it does not create an object, so you cannot use them in a list or tuple or anything; slice *objects* on the other hand actually refer to the thing returned by `slice()` which behave the same, and that's what Numpy is referencing with "tuple of slice objects and integers". The valid syntax to do what you were expecting would be `Z[(slice(1, 2), slice(2, 3), 1)]`. This allows you to save slices to a variable and use them instead.

Here's a simple code snippet to demonstrate:

```py
>>> 1:2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
>>> slice(1, 2)
slice(1, 2, None)
>>> [1, 2, 3][1:2]
[2]
>>> [1, 2, 3][slice(1, 2)]
[2]
```

Comment: For ```[1, 2, 3][1:2]```, when ```1:2``` is inside a square block [, the Python interpreter regards it as a expression, evaluate it, create slice(1:2) object?

Comment: @mon I don't think it "creates" a slice object, but it does the equivalent thing. It's part of the Python language syntax: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html